How to make group by in django ORM
I've an Order model as below:
class Order(models.Model):
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    address_from = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    address_to = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

How can I group a queryset from it and iterate in each group like the following:
bill = models.Bill.objects.get(pk=1)
groups = models.Order.objects.all().group_by('address_from', 'address_to')

for group in groups:
    group.update(bill = bill)

The point is to assign a specific Bill instance for each group of the orders that have the same address from and address to.

I've solved this problem by combining the address from & address to primary keys into annotated unique key - uk - field and filter each uk.
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

orders = models.Order.objects.annotate(
    addresses_uk=Concat('address_from__pk', Value('-'), 'address_to__pk',
        output_field=CharField())
    )

for uk in set(orders.values_list('addresses_uk', flat=True)):
    bill = models.Bill.objects.create(
        address_from=models.Address.objects.get(pk=int(uk.split("-")[0])),
        address_to=models.Address.objects.get(pk=int(uk.split("-")[1]))
    )
    orders.filter(addresses_uk=uk).update(bill=bill)


To do what you're looking for, there is no group_by as such, in your place I'd make a list with all the unique combinations of your 2 address fields, For each group, filter the corresponding commands and use update() to assign the specified instance of Bill
You can find more information in the documentation, particularly in the sections on values() and distinct()
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/models/querysets/
I hope my answer helps solve your problem

@Ahmed Ashraf answered the question. We can however retrieve and create data in bulk, which will boost performance a lot, with:
orders = {
    (order.address_from, order.adress_to): order
    for order in models.Order.objects.filter(bill=None)
}

bills = []
for (item1, item2), order in orders.items():
    bill = models.Bill(address_from_id=item1, address_to_id=item2)
    bills.append(bill)
    order.bill = bill

for bill in Bill.objects.bulk_create(bills):
  orders[bill.address_from_id, bill.address_to_id].bill = bill

Order.objects.bulk_update(orders.values(), fields=('bill',))
or for databases that don't return the primary keys for a .bulk_create(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Q

orders = {
    (order.address_from, order.adress_to): order
    for order in models.Order.objects.filter(bill=None)
}

bills = []
records = []
for (item1, item2), order in orders.items():
    bill = models.Bill(address_from_id=item1, address_to_id=item2)
    bills.append(bill)
    order.bill = bill
    records.append(Q(address_from_id=item1, address_to_id=item2))

Bill.objects.bulk_create(bills)

bills = Bill.objects.filter(Q(records, _connector=Q.OR)).order_by('pk')
for bill in bills:
    orders[bill.address_from_id, bill.address_to_id].bill = bill

Order.objects.bulk_update(orders.values(), fields=('bill',))
This will work with three queries: one to fetch all orders without a bill, one to create all bills, and finally one to update all the Orders with the created Bills. In the last scenario, it will make four database queries.

Thank you for your help, your solution works well but the bills instances are not being linked to their appropriate orders.
The bill field on each order is still null after running the code.

@AhmedAshraf: did you run Order.objects.bulk_update(orders.values(), fields=('bill',))?

Yes I did, the bills are being created but not linked to any order.

@AhmedAshraf: What Django and database version do you use? Did you include the second for loop in the edit?

Thank you for your time and effort in making the code performs better, I'm using django 3.2, SQLite, Yes I've included the 2nd loop.

@AhmedAshraf: what sqlite version?

willeM_ Van Onsem Sqlite3

@AhmedAshraf: what if you use the second version of the code. SQLite indeed does not returns the primary keys of the created Bill records.
